# New row per button click in data grid view

Tags: c#, datagridview

How can I display a new row everytime I click ? Because what it do is it replaces the value of the first row instead of adding a new line.

```
  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
      dtbl.Columns.Add("1st Header");
      dtbl.Columns.Add("2nd Header");
      dtbl.Columns.Add("3rd Header");

      dtbl.Rows.Add("1","2","3");                

      dgv.DataSource = dtbl;
 }
```

Comment: If you already have the data table, why not just use the .Rows.Add instead of setting the data source all over again?

Comment: Rows cannot be programmatically added to the datagridview's row collection when the control is data-bound

Answer (score 1):

Because on every click you initialize a new data table.
Put your `DataTable` initialization and datasource assignment into another function and make your `DataTable` private so that you can use it in button click -

```
    DataTable dtbl;
    private void InitializeDataTable()
    {
        dtbl = new DataTable();
        dtbl.Columns.Add("1st Header");
        dtbl.Columns.Add("2nd Header");
        dtbl.Columns.Add("3rd Header");

        dgv.DataSource = dtbl;
    }
```

Now, in button click, add the new row using [DataTable.NewRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx) -

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow newRow = dtbl.NewRow();
        dtbl.Rows.Add(newRow);

        dgv.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Rows cannot be programmatically added to the datagridview's row collection when the control is data-bound

Comment: ERROR: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Where? Which line? have you called the `InitializeDataTable` method anywhere?

Comment: You are probably getting error because you never called the `InitializeDataTable`. Try calling it in form load or form constructor..